# Everytime i have to import my collection api for insertin and diplaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

i am making web app using meteor with react and in my LedgerMaster.jsx  is

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
   import { LedgerMasterApi } from '../../../api/ledgerMaster';
   import  LedgerMasterForm  from './LedgerMasterForm';
   import  LedgerMasterDiplay  from './LedgerMasterDiplay';
    class LedgerMaster extends Component {
    render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <LedgerMasterForm />
          <LedgerMasterDiplay ledgeres={this.props.ledgeres}  />
        </div>
       );
      }
    }
 export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
     ledgeres: LedgerMasterApi.find({}).fetch(),
    };
 }, LedgerMaster);
```

so the problem is i have to define my  `import { LedgerMasterApi } from '../../../api/ledgerMaster';` in both LedgerMasterForm for insertion and LedgerMasterDiplay for fetch  data

Comment: You tell us, what does it produce?

Comment: i am littleconfuse how would i print my categories and sub categories like above so i posted this question if some one helps me for this

Comment: Well show us an example of the resultset produced by the query

Comment: its showing invalid relational operator

Comment: which database product? You have this tagged with MySQL and Oracle - it can't be both.

Comment: Your categories and sub-categories have an id and a name. Are they ordered in any particular way? Or do you not care about the order in which the categories are listed, and then the order of the subcategories within each category? If you need them ordered, there must be additional information in the table; relational table rows are not ordered by default.

Comment: my mistake i apologize its oracle

Comment: c001 electronics c002 home appliances and sub categoris are sc001 mobile sc002 mobile with cat id c001

Comment: Question came a little under-prepared, but does not deserve its high negative rating. Category / Subcategory listings seems to be a common problem for which I did not find a good answer yet on StackOverflow. I am sure if someone get's this properly answered, it will be useful for others. I did find a full-sql solution for this, but it does not lend itself well for a language with the concept of Cursors (ResultSets).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure. try this work what u want.

use this query.

```
SELECT category.catnap,sub_category.subcatname  FROM category
INNER JOIN sub_category ON TRIM(category.canid) = TRIM(sub_category.canid)  ORDER BY category.catnap ASC
```

use this code

```
while(rs.next()){
       out.println(rs.getString("catnap")+"."+rs.getString("subcatname"));
}
```

Comment: your result should looks like this?

`electronics.mobile   
electronics.Coumputer   
home appliances.AC   
home appliances.Freez   
furniture.Sofa`

Comment: Ya kind a same bt category name shouldno repeat

Comment: Ya sir i did it thank you so much for your help . I did it in a diffrent way see below i  have answered it . It cant be possible without you . Sir could you plz give your email id i want to be in contact with you

Answer (score 0):

```
    rs=stat.executeQuery("select count(catname) as numRows, catname from category group by catname");
    while(rs.next()){
        String cat="";int count=0;
       int catrow=rs.getInt("numRows");
       for (int j=1;j<=catrow.length;j++){
           count=0;
           cat=rs.getString("catname");
           system.out.println(cat);
           rs1=stat.executeQuery("SELECT sub.subcatname from sub_category sub where sub.catid="+'cat'+);

           while(rs1.next()){
               system.out.println(rs1.getString("subcategory"));
               count++;
           }
       }

}
```

Comment: Needs some extra work: 1./ code won't compile, 2./ it has the beginnings of [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), 3./ `count(catnap)` should be a simple  count(*), unless you expect values to be null; 4./ poor query reuse - begs for a `PreparedStatement`. But with a little extra love, it can be recycled as the accepted answer.

Comment: thanx alot Bhugy for your effort bt i will not work as i know that we cant put a query  inside a another query

Comment: my project has stuck here can anyone help me for geting that output.